# private_pub gem gives "undefined method `publish_to'" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faye, private-pub

I am creating small chat app with rails, I am using private_pub (built on top of faye) gem by Ryan. I followed all steps as per his screencast , but i can't get it working. I am getting below error

```
undefined method `publish_to' for #<#<Class:0x007f95964f5398>:0x007f95925e6378>
```

I am including publish_to in chat.js.coffee.erb

```
msgJson = (message)->
    time = $.now()
    <% publish_to "/chats/new" do %>
      append_chat_message(time,message)
    <% end %>
```

Both my thin and faye servers are running , i used below command to start he faye

```
rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production
```

I included subscribe_to line in my template

```
<%= subscribe_to "/chats/new" %>
```

and also added assets

```
//= require private_pub
```

I don't know , where its going wrong. Any help will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself, if we using Private_pub only the Rails app can publish to channels  , we need write the pusblish_to function in call back file of ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You've to install

```
gem 'thin'
```

and then restart the server again. It worked for me. Hope it works for you also.